# How to update GIMP in Ubuntu 16.04 using snaps?

Tags: updates, snap, gimp

I know that an application (GIMP) has had a recent update from 2.8.16 to 2.8.18 to fix some security issues. This recent update is not being pushed out by Snappy for Ubuntu 16.04.  I know this because I have a PPA on another machine running Ubuntu 14.04 which keeps GIMP up to date. The PPA keeps the software current on 14.04.  How do I ask Snappy to update GIMP on 16.04?

Comment: The 2.8.18 version of Gimp is in Ubuntu 16.04 repository. What do you mean by "not being pushed out by Snappy"?

Comment: I have GIMP installed in Ubuntu Studio 16.04 which uses the XFCE interface.  When I go to Software, it shows GIMP as being installed and that the current version installed is 2.8.16.  I verify that by opening GIMP and going to About.  There it shows 2.8.16.    Software says all apps are up-to-date.   I get regular OS updates which I install.

Comment: I ran Synaptic and it shows the latest version being 2.8.16.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIMP 2.8.18 has not reached Ubuntu repositories yet.

If you need 2.8.18 now so badly, you can install it from PPA this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp
```

At the moment of writing this, Gimp will be upgraded to 2.8.18.

Comment: GIMP 2.8.18 will most likely never be in the 16.04 repositories; instead, the bug fixes are backported to 2.8.16.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies the question.   I was led to believe it had reached the repositories and was trying to figure out why the software updates hadn't picked it up.   I was told there was a security vulnerability with XCF files and was just trying to keep my system patched.

Comment: @fkraiem Who told you that? I've never seen that Gimp had any backports in Ubuntu.

Comment: @jerrysvoice That PPA has alway the latest Gimp for all Ubuntu supproted versions.

Comment: Security-related fixes are backported, and have been in this case. You just won't get 2.8.18.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the PPA as I had on 14.04.   Everything is up-to-date now.  Thanks.

Comment: You can accept the correct answer by clicking the check sign at the left. I got 2 downvotes already ;-) @jerrysvoice

Comment: This issue is solved with PPA from Otto Kessel.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the `gimp` package in the 16.04 repositories (which is `2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1`) includes a fix for the XCF vulnerability ([CVE-2016-4994](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-4994)). From the [Ubuntu changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/g/gimp/gimp_2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1/changelog):

```
gimp (2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1) xenial-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: multiple issues in XCF channel and layer properties
    - debian/patches/CVE-2016-4994.patch: properly clear pointers in
      app/xcf/xcf-load.c.
    - CVE-2016-4994

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 30 Jun 2016 12:40:34 -0400
```

Thus if you are only interested in this bug fix, and not in any other thing which was introduced in 2.8.18, there is no need to update your `gimp` package through other means.

Comment: That makes sense.